# Why won't my form watermarking script work anymore?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, jquery-plugins

I had a watermarked form on my website, working perfectly using a watermarking script ( I still have an old version where it works fine.) Today I noticed it suddenly stopped working and I cannot figure out why. I cross-checked the styles and script with that of the earlier (still working) version, and it's all identical. Any ideas?

Here's a comparison for reference:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/deoJt.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/deoJt.png#1

Here's my site

[www.artyst-tyrant.com](http://www.artyst-tyrant.com)

Designer by trade who's trying his hand at learning to code, but I'm by no means a pro, so please, go easy.

Thank you in advance for your help, it's really appreciated.

Comment: can you provide us some of the code where you think the issue might be? Any relevant code will better help us to help you. Nice looking design on that site by the way.

Comment: It's not working because you have an error in your code. Line 434,       <div class="grid_5 push_1" style="padding-right:20px;"">. Notice the extra quote :).

Comment: Btw, the placeholders (watermarks, whatever) appear correctly for me in Chrome and FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only invalid thing I found is that in the event handlers, you don't specify the ID selector: `$("name")[0].focus();` - missing `#`. You don't even need to, because you can use `this` there.

```
    $("#name").click(
        function () {
            this.focus();
        }
    );
```

Also simplified your code a bit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $elements = $('#name, #mail, #message');
        var texts = {
            'mail': 'Email',
            'name': 'Name',
            'message': 'Message'
        };

        $elements.each(function () {
            $(this).watermark(texts[this.id]);
        }).click(function () {
            this.focus();
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

I found this piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#name").watermark("Name");
        $("#name").click(
            function () {
                $("name")[0].focus();
            }
        );
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#mail").watermark("Email");
        $("#mail").click(
            function () {
                $("mail")[0].focus();
            }
        );
    });


    $(function () {
        $("#message").watermark("Message");
        $("#message").click(
            function () {
                $("message")[0].focus();
            }
        );
    });

</script>
```

`$(function() {...` throws an error in FireFox ("`$(function() {...` *is not valid*).

Even this is equal to `$(document).ready(function() {...}` you can give it a try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#name").watermark("Name");
        $("#name").click(
            function () {
                $("name")[0].focus();
            }
        );


        $("#mail").watermark("Email");
        $("#mail").click(
            function () {
                $("mail")[0].focus();
            }
        );

        $("#message").watermark("Message");
        $("#message").click(
            function () {
                $("message")[0].focus();
            }
        );
    }); 
</script>
```

I wrapped your code into `$(document).ready` so it gets executed when your document is ready: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Why would not it be valid? You should read the page you linked.

Comment: Actually, that's the shortcut for `$(document).ready`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

Comment: @bažmegakapa I read, but FireFox showed a JavaScript Error in exactly that line.

Comment: @VictorBeazzo Don't forget to accept the answer if it has helped

Comment: @Raubi We should try to figure out why it helps then :D. The syntax is valid, there must be something else.

Comment: @bažmegakapa Yes, I'm sorry. I mispelled a bit. I'm editing my answer for that.

Comment: @Raubi My Firefox does not throw said error.

Comment: This is not a solution, the watermark code didn't get executed because there is a syntax error before it. So by calling the same code before that error, it should work for him, yet it's not a solution and it maybe misleading.